# get delegate does not take 1 argument error when using linq

Tags: c#, linq

i am trying to add the statement after i form the linq statement. However, i get this error after i verified the code is correct. Why it cause the error?

[image]

```
     query3 = query3.Where(a => a.product_group_id.Contains(1));
```

i added the using System.Linq.Dynamic; on the top.

Comment: Hint- Look at the number of arguments you've provided.

Comment: i think the reason is the product group id is the int? << thats why the boolean cannot contain 1

Comment: .Where((a, e) => ....)

Comment: Do you have `using System.Linq;` as well? Perhaps `System.Linq.Dynamic` only provides a `Where` overload accepting two arguments. It's not clear why you're trying to use `System.Linq.Dynamic` at all here.

Comment: system.linq included

Comment: @Aominè not work, is still same error

Comment: i think the main reason is the int is the nullable int

Comment: no i tested, it is not nullable int issue

Comment: https://s1.postimg.org/8mic96enhb/Untitled.png

Comment: Your new picture shows that `int?` was the issue with the first error, and your new issue is that the type of `query3` doesn't match the type of the expression. Where is `query3` declared / initialized?

Comment: Also, why did you think `int?` implemented `Contains` or that calling `Contains` on `int?` makes any logical sense?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
 var query3 = query3.Where(a => a.product_group_id == 1).Select(i=>i).ToList();
```

.Where() returns IEnumerable. You can't mix Contains with Where, since the first returns bool, not int.

Try .Any() if you want to check if db has the element with specified condition.

```
bool query3 = query3.Any(a => a.product_group_id == 1);
```

.Contains() returns bool. It only check if the OBJECT exists.

```
bool query3 = query3.Contains(yourProduct);
```